# Aggregating a sparse matrix by a single column

Tags: r

I have a very large sparse matrix that looks like:

```
 client item_1 item_2 item_3.... item_n
  a       1      0      0          0
  a       0      0      1          0
  b       0      1      0          0
  b       1      0      0          0
```

and so on...

I would like to aggregate the matrix by the client column to obtain:

```
client item_1 item_2 item_3.... item_n
  a       1      0      1          0
  b       1      1      0          0
```

I have tried to convert back to a dense matrix and then aggregate, but run into memory issues.

My data look like

```
new("dgCMatrix"
    , i = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 1L)
    , p = c(0L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 8L)
    , Dim = 4:5
    , Dimnames = list(NULL, c("client", "item_1", "item_2", "item_3", "item_n"
))
    , x = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    , factors = list()
)
```

Comment: Try `aggregate(.~client, df1, sum)`

Comment: or.. `with(d, rowsum(d[-1], client))` . But can you be a bit more clear over your structure please. Is it actually a sparseMatrix class object, as afaik you cant have character variables

Comment: Yep, it is a sparseMatrix, so the client variables are 1,2,3 instead of a,b,c. aggregate(.~client, df1, sum) does not work because it is a sparseMatrix.

Comment: @deadasdreams ; can you confirm that the structure I have added to your question is accurate please. If not, can you update. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Matrix multiplication of sparse matrices solves the problem (your matrix is b):

```
fac2sparse(b[,1]) %*% b[,-1]
```

A difference is that the client column is now found as the row names.

Aggregating by a single factorial variable is a special case of more advanced problems that can be solved by functions within the package SSBtools:

```
clientFrame <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(b[, 1, drop = FALSE]))
# Two lines below are both same as fac2sparse(b[,1]) %*% b[,-1]
t(FormulaSums(clientFrame, ~client - 1)) %*% b[, -1]
t(Hierarchies2ModelMatrix(clientFrame, list(client = ""))) %*% b[, -1]
# Two lines below add overall totals
t(FormulaSums(clientFrame, ~client)) %*% b[, -1]
t(Hierarchies2ModelMatrix(clientFrame, list(client = "Total"))) %*% b[, -1]
```